# Delay only some function

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu

I have code which control thermometer, OLED and nanoservo via MQTT. I want to refresh temperature every 10s. It works but my servo receive command only when temperature is refreshed. How can I configure my loop so my servo can receive MQTT command anytime I send it?

Here in my code (I combined several example codes...):

```
    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    #include <Servo.h>
    #include <PubSubClient.h>

    #include <OneWire.h>
    #include <DallasTemperature.h>

    #include <Wire.h>
    #include "SH1106.h"
    #include "thermometer.h"

    // Data wire is plugged into pin 2 on the Arduino
    #define ONE_WIRE_BUS 14 // je D5 was 2 (D4)

    // Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices 
    // (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs)
    OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

    // Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature.
    DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

    SH1106 display(0x3c, D1, D2);
    #define DEMO_DURATION 3000
    typedef void (*Demo)(void);

    int demoMode = 0;
    int counter = 1;

    // Update these with values suitable for your network.

    const char* ssid = "******";
    const char* password = "******";
    const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.100.220";     /// MQTT  Broker
    const char* topic_state = "/blinds/state";
    const char* topic_command = "/blinds/command";

    IPAddress my_ip (192, 168, 100, 224);
    IPAddress my_gateway (192,168, 100, 1);
    IPAddress my_subnet (255, 255, 255, 0);

    WiFiClient espClient;
    PubSubClient client(espClient);
    long lastMsg = 0;
    char msg[50];
    int value = 0;

    Servo myservo;
    int state = 0;
    int prevstate = 0;
    int dirc = 0;
    int spintime = 0;
    int servoPin = D4; //CHANGE TO WHATEVETR PIN YOUR USING

    void reconnect();
    void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length);

    void setup() { 
      Serial.begin(115200);
      setup_wifi();
      client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
      client.setCallback(callback);

    // Start up the library
      sensors.begin();

    // Initialising the UI will init the display too.
      display.init();
      display.flipScreenVertically();
      display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_10);

    }

    void servo_move() {
      Serial.println("State Change. Rotating Servo");
      if ( dirc == 180) {
        client.publish(topic_state,"open");
      }
      else if (dirc == 0) {
        client.publish(topic_state,"close");  
    }
      myservo.attach(servoPin);
      myservo.write(dirc);
      delay(spintime);
      myservo.detach();

      Serial.println("Returning to main loop");
      return;
    }

    void setup_wifi() {

      delay(10);
      // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Connecting to ");
      Serial.println(ssid);

      WiFi.setPhyMode(WIFI_PHY_MODE_11N);
      WiFi.config(my_ip, my_gateway, my_subnet);
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }

      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("WiFi connected");
      Serial.println("IP address: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    }

    void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
      Serial.print("Message arrived [");
      Serial.print(topic);
      Serial.print("] ");
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
      }
      Serial.println();
      char *blindcommand = (char *) payload; // convert mqtt byte array into char array
      blindcommand[length] ='\0';            // Must delimit with 0

      Serial.print(blindcommand);
      if (strcmp(blindcommand,"open") == 0) {
        Serial.println(" 433MHZ OPEN COMMAND RECEIVED");
        dirc = 180; // direction for servo to run
        spintime = 50; // << CHANGE TO WHATEVER TIME YOU NEED TO OPEN YOUR BLINDS
        state = 1; //sets current state
      }
      else if (strcmp(blindcommand,"close") == 0) {
        Serial.println(" 433MHZ CLOSE COMMAND RECEIVED");
        dirc = 0;
        spintime = 150; // << CHANGE TO WHATEVER TIME YOU NEED TO CLOSE YOUR BLINDS
        state = 2; //sets current state
      }
      if (state != prevstate) {
        Serial.println("State change!");
        servo_move();
      }
      prevstate = state;

    }
    char temperatureVonku[15];
    String tempUnit = " °C";

    void temperature(){
      float temperatureFloat;
      sensors.requestTemperatures();
      temperatureFloat = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);

      dtostrf(temperatureFloat, 7, 1, temperatureVonku);

       client.publish("temp/outside", temperatureVonku);    /// send char
       delay(10000);
    }

    void dispTempVonku() {
        display.drawRect(1, 1, DISPLAY_WIDTH -1, DISPLAY_HEIGHT -1);
        // Font Demo1
        // create more fonts at http://oleddisplay.squix.ch/
        display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
        display.setFont(Roboto_Bold_12);
        display.drawString(5, 5, "Temp: ");

        display.drawXbm(7, 24, Img_width, Img_height, thermometer);
        display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER);
        display.setFont(Roboto_Bold_28);
        display.drawString(64, 22, temperatureVonku + tempUnit);
    }
    void dispTempVnutri() {  
        display.drawRect(1, 1, DISPLAY_WIDTH -1, DISPLAY_HEIGHT -1);
        display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER);
        display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_16);
        display.drawString(64, 22, "Hello World");
    }

    Demo demos[] = {dispTempVonku, dispTempVnutri};
    int demoLength = (sizeof(demos) / sizeof(Demo));
    long timeSinceLastModeSwitch = 0;


    void reconnect() {
      // Loop until we're reconnected
      while (!client.connected()) {
        Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
        // Attempt to connect
        if (client.connect("ESP8266Client", "******", "******")) {

          Serial.println("connected");
          client.subscribe(topic_command);
        } else {
          Serial.print("failed, rc=");
          Serial.print(client.state());
          Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
          // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
          delay(5000);
        }
      }
    }
    void loop() {

     temperature();   

      if (!client.connected()) {
        reconnect();

      }
      client.loop();
      // clear the display
      display.clear();
      // draw the current demo method
      demos[demoMode]();

      display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_RIGHT);
      display.drawString(10, 128, String(millis()));
      // write the buffer to the display
      display.display();

      if (millis() - timeSinceLastModeSwitch > DEMO_DURATION) {
        demoMode = (demoMode + 1)  % demoLength;
        timeSinceLastModeSwitch = millis();
      }
      counter++;

     //delay(10000);


    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: please follow the below links, might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452394/best-way-to-perform-an-action-periodically-while-an-app-is-running-handler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397973/how-to-read-continuous-data-and-display-it

Comment: MQTT does not guarantee delivery times. Delays between publishing and receiving can reach 2-3 seconds in a local configuration. If you are using an Internet broker, it's worse.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your servo only receives data when you keep the delay(10000).

The problem is that with a delay, the Arduino does kind of nothing during that time, so it cannot control your servo.

What you want is to call every 10 s the temperature update, but keep the servo control always running.

So keep a last-time-called variable (type unsigned long) that keeps the time of the last call to update the temperature. When 10 s have passed (you can check somewhere in the loop), you call it, and update the last time to the current time.